# How long takes to Cloudbees repository syncs with Maven Central?

Tags: cloudbees, maven-central

I deployed a war application to Maven Central through oss.sonaytpe.org. The war can be accessed at http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/br/com/thiagomoreira/liferay/plugins/bootstrap-jumbotron-theme/1.0.0.0/bootstrap-jumbotron-theme-1.0.0.0.war, it was deployed 4 hours ago at least and it is still not available in http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/repositories/central/. I have another project the relies on the given war to be deployed but I got stuck in this issue. I have two questions: why central is proxied? How long takes to repo.cloudbees.com get in sync with Central? This shouldn't be transparent like a real proxy?
  I'm postponing the release of my project to the next weekend due this road block. #fail

Answer (score 0):

repo.cloudbees.com is a (nexus) proxy to access central, it will cache artifacts first time it is requested from a build : 
http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/repositories/central/br/com/thiagomoreira/liferay/plugins/bootstrap-jumbotron-theme/1.0.0.0/bootstrap-jumbotron-theme-1.0.0.0.war

Answer (score 0):

everything that you said is right in theory and I knew that before posting my question. But the reality was different, look the screenshot that I took when I was trying to release my project. I pretty sure there is some misconfiguration in between central and cloudbees...

[image: screenshot of the missing artifact]